# Projective Transformations Mapping $k$-dimensional subspaces to $k$-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

I want to learn an algorithmic approach to solve the following general problem: How to find **all** elements in $PGL(n+1,K)$ which maps a $k$-dimensional subspace, say $U$, of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ to another $k$-dimensional subspace, say $W$, of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$?

I guess i know how to solve this question for one element. In other words, suppose i just need to find one element of $PGL(n+1,K)$ mapping $U$ to $W$. Then, we can do the following, I guess:

1- Write $U = <p_{1},...,p_{k}>$ for some points $p_{1},...,p_{k}$

2- Write $W = <q_{1},...,q_{k}>$ for some points $q_{1},...,q_{k}$

3- Extend both lists to frames. Since $PGL(n+1,K)$ acts regularly on frames of $P^{n}$, we are done.

As a concrete example: Find all elements of $PGL(4,K)$ which maps $L_{1}$ to $L_{2}$ where $L_{1} = <(1,2,1,1),(2,3,1,0)>$ and $L_{2} = <(1,1,1,2),(3,1,0,1)>$.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: @MorganRodgers unfortunately, I do not know about the quotient spaces. Is there another way to tackle the problem?

Comment: Are you able to follow your steps 1., 2., 3., for your concrete example of lines in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$? How about finding the set of elements that send $L_{1}$ to itself?

Comment: * If you know how to do this for "one element", meaning to find all the maps stabilizing a $k$-space $U$, this is a subgroup of $\mathrm{PGL}(n+1,K)$; then the collection of elements sending $U \mapsto W$ is a coset of this subgroup. Are you having trouble finding a single such map?

Comment: @MorganRodgers thank you very much for your answers. I can follow the steps for my concrete example and also I can find stabilizer of a line as well. If I understand your comments correctly, you are saying that all maps that sends $U$ to $W$ is of the form: $BA$ where A is the map I found which maps L1 to L2 and B is any stabiliser of L2, is it true?

Comment: I think you may need the map $AB$ instead of $BA$ (you need to apply the map stabilizing $U$ first). Also you need to allow maps $B$ that stabilize $U$ as a subspace, and not just fix a given frame. But otherwise, yes this is what I'm saying.